# Bcrypt error: Illegal arguments: string, undefined

Tags: node.js, express, jwt, backend, bcrypt

I am trying to create a login end point and sending auth token
but when i am sending request for creating user it works fine but when i send request for login authentication it is sending response as internal server error and in console it is sending me this error:-

```
Illegal arguments: string, undefined
[nodemon] restarting due to changes...
[nodemon] starting `node server.js index.js`
    at _async (D:\Web Development\REACT PROJECTS\inotebook\backend\node_modules\bcryptjs\dist\bcrypt.js:286:46)    at D:\Web Development\REACT PROJECTS\inotebook\backend\node_modules\bcryptjs\dist\bcrypt.js:307:17
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at Object.bcrypt.compare (D:\Web Development\REACT PROJECTS\inotebook\backend\node_modules\bcryptjs\dist\bcrypt.js:306:20)
7:17    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at Object.bcrypt.compare (D:\Web Development\REACT PROJECTS\inotebook\backend\node_modules\bcryptjs\dist\bcrypt.js:306:20)
    at D:\Web Development\REACT PROJECTS\inotebook\backend\routes\auth.js:73:42    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
```

Here is my complete code of auth.js:-

```
const express = require('express');
const User = require('../models/User');
const router = express.Router();
const { body, validationResult } = require('express-validator');
const bcrypt = require('bcryptjs');
var jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');

const JWT_SECRET = 'usisagoodb$oy';

// Create a User using: POST "/api/auth/createuser". No login required
router.post('/createuser', [
  body('name', 'Enter a valid name').isLength({ min: 3 }),
  body('email', 'Enter a valid email').isEmail(),
  body('password', 'Password must be atleast 5 characters').isLength({ min: 5 }),
], async (req, res) => {
  // If there are errors, return Bad request and the errors
  const errors = validationResult(req);
  if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
    return res.status(400).json({ errors: errors.array() });
  }
  try {
    // Check whether the user with this email exists already
    let user = await User.findOne({ email: req.body.email });
    if (user) {
      return res.status(400).json({ error: "Sorry a user with this email already exists" })
    }
    const salt = await bcrypt.genSalt(10);
    const secPass = await bcrypt.hash(req.body.password, salt);

    // Create a new user
    user = await User.create({
      name: req.body.name,
      password: secPass,
      email: req.body.email,
    });
    const data = {
      user:{
        id: user.id
      }
    }
    const authtoken = jwt.sign(data, JWT_SECRET);
    

    // res.json(user)
    res.json({authtoken})
    
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error.message);
    res.status(500).send("Internal Server Error");
  }
})


// Authenticate a User using: POST "/api/auth/login". No login required
router.post('/login', [ 
  body('email', 'Enter a valid email').isEmail(), 
  body('password', 'Password cannot be blank').exists(), 
], async (req, res) => {

  // If there are errors, return Bad request and the errors
  const errors = validationResult(req);
  if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
    return res.status(400).json({ errors: errors.array() });
  }

  const {email, password} = req.body;
  try {
    let user = await User.findOne({email});
    if(!user){
      return res.status(400).json({error: "Please try to login with correct credentials"});
    }

    const passwordCompare = await bcrypt.compare(password, user.password);
    if(!passwordCompare){
      return res.status(400).json({error: "Please try to login with correct credentials"});
    }

    const data = {
      user:{
        id: user.id
      }
    }
    const authtoken = jwt.sign(data, JWT_SECRET);
    res.json({authtoken})

  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
    res.status(500).send("Internal Server Error");
  }


})
module.exports = router
```

i also tried to replace
const bcrypt = require('bcryptjs');
with
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt');

but this also gave me this error:-

```
Error: data and hash arguments required    at Object.compare (D:\Web Development\REACT PROJECTS\inotebook\backend\node_modules\bcrypt\bcrypt.js:208:17)
    at D:\Web Development\REACT PROJECTS\inotebook\backend\node_modules\bcrypt\promises.js:29:12  
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at Object.module.exports.promise (D:\Web Development\REACT PROJECTS\inotebook\backend\node_modules\bcrypt\promises.js:20:12)
    at Object.compare (D:\Web Development\REACT PROJECTS\inotebook\backend\node_modules\bcrypt\bcrypt.js:204:25)
    at D:\Web Development\REACT PROJECTS\inotebook\backend\routes\auth.js:73:42
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
```

MAINLY IT IS GIVING ME ERROR ON THIS PART OF CODE WHEN I AM USING bcrypt.compare function

```
const {email, password} = req.body;
  try {
    let user = await User.findOne({email});
    if(!user){
      return res.status(400).json({error: "Please try to login with correct credentials"});
    }

    const passwordCompare = await bcrypt.compare(password, user.password);
    if(!passwordCompare){
      return res.status(400).json({error: "Please try to login with correct credentials"});
    }
```

Comment: This error means your parameters are null or undefined. Try let user = await User.findOne({email : email}); since you have declared "email".

Answer (score 0):

The only thing that looks out of place is

```
let user = await User.findOne({email});
```

it should be like:

```
let user = await User.findOne({where:{email}});
```

as you can also see in the [documentation](https://sequelize.org/docs/v6/core-concepts/model-querying-finders/#findone)

Comment: it is giving same error using this also

Error: data and hash arguments required

Comment: with bcrypt? try user.dataValues.password and let me know if this fixes issue

Answer (score 0):

```
const userEmail=req.body.email;
const userPassword=req.body.password;
let user = await User.findOne({email:userEmail});
```

And you should use bcrypt instead of bcryptjs

Comment: Can you pls elaborate it, and tell me where i should add this code.

Comment: In Your Login Route Where you have define const {email,password}=req.body and put all that thing inside try block you have put this outside the try block